# please help me to find the error in this C code

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am a beginner to c language. Please help me to find the error of the code as it gives a complilation error on the display.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    char i;
    char arr[23];

    printf("Enter your name? \n");`
    scanf("%c",&arr[i]);

    for(int v=0;v<=strlen(arr);v++)
    {
        printf("%c",arr[v]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest `fgets(arr, sizeof arr, stdin);` to input name. BTW your code will accept only a single character.

Comment: You haven't initialized `i`. Enable compiler warnings and read them.

Comment: `main` must return a `int`, not `void`.

Comment: "Gives an error"? What error

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)  Turn on all compiler warnings. For compiler errors chop code down until OK & add back. Runtime find & show input & output up to the 1st point that doesn't have the program in the state you expect. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several issues, not only one:

#### 1.

You use the wrong format specifier `%c` to catch a single character instead of `%s` to catch a string:

```
char arr[23];
printf("Enter your name: \n");`
scanf("%c",&arr[i]);
```

Rather use `scanf("%s",arr);` or even better `scanf("%Ns",arr);` where `N` stands for the maximum number of characters to be entered. Note that you need one element for the string-terminating null character, so it requires to be at least one character less than the `char` array is consisted of.

You can also use `fgets(arr,23,stdin)` which is preferred for consuming strings from the standard input because it is more safe as it requires you to provide the maximum amount of characters to read (counting the null character too) and also reads white space separated words as part of the string by default.

---

#### 2.

`i` is not initialized to any value, so:

```
scanf("%c",&arr[i]);
```

causes undefined behavior.

---

#### 3.

Furthermore you try to get a string length by using `strlen()` as part of the condition expression of the for loop:

```
for(int v = 0; v <= strlen(arr); v++)
```

although there is no valid string in `arr` which causes also undefined behavior.

As a side note here: It is more efficient to use `strlen()` only once before the for loop, store its return value in an object of an appropriate type (`size_t` is the type of the return value of `strlen()`) and use that object in the condition of the for loop instead of executing `strlen()` before each iteration.

---

#### 4.

Next thing is that you *attempt* to print characters inside the for loop which aren´t provided/initialized to `arr`:

```
for(int v = 0; v <= strlen(arr); v++)
{
   printf("%c",arr[v]);
}
```

---

#### 5.

The for loop with the condition `v <= strlen()`:

```
for(int v = 0; v <= strlen(arr); v++)
```

runs one time more than expected and prints the null character which is redundant since the null character is not printable.

Rather use `v < strlen()` or according to point 3:

```
    size_t len = strlen(arr);

    for(int v = 0; v < len; v++)
```

---

#### 6.

The return value of `main` shall be `int`, not `void`.

---

#### 7.

There is a trailing apostrophe after the `printf()` call:

```
printf("Enter your name: \n");`
```

---

Rather use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[23];

    printf("Enter your name: \n");

    scanf("%22s",arr);

    printf("%s",arr);
}
```

[Online Example](https://onlinegdb.com/r1mISt4DI)

if you want to print out the string entered as whole at once, or:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[23];

    printf("Enter your name: \n");

    scanf("%22s",arr);

    size_t len = strlen(arr);

    for(int v = 0; v < len; v++)
    {
        printf("%c",arr[v]);
    }        
}
```

[Online example](https://onlinegdb.com/BJ088FEwI)

if you want to print each character separate.

Comment: Pay attention that there is still the ` at the end of line printf("Enter your name: \n"); `.

Comment: @Eddymage I´m pretty sure that this was just a formatting issue on pasting the code on SO and is relatively irrelevant in comparison to the other issues in that code.

Comment: You're right that there are (plenty) of issues, the main one (I still do not understand if it was the actual error that the user was getting) is the returning value of `main`. The other problems did not throw any error in compilation time, even if the output was completely wring.

Comment: @Eddymage The compiler doesn´t need to throw a warning, although code may have massive problems in it which then occur at run-time or maybe only at a specific use-case years after. That is something we all need to be aware of.

Comment: your are completely right, but the user ask for the error that appeared in the display whan he/she tried to compile the code. At first glance, the first error is the ` in the line of printf, but it is clear that also the return value of the main is the other error thrown by the compiler, once the typo is fixed. The others are not even runtime errors, since the code works but display wrong chars and/or results (at least, on my laptop).

Comment: @Eddymage I finally incorporated it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not really an error. You have an extra character in this lane:

```
 printf("Enter your name? \n");`
```

It should be:

```
 printf("Enter your name? \n");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a ` at end of the line

```
printf("Enter your name? \n");`
```

Answer (score 0):

note you are using uninitialized `int i` here `scanf("%c",&arr[i]);` which is wrong.

also with `scanf("%c",&arr[i]);` you can only scan one character for string `arr` which I think is not your purpose.

you can use `scanf("%s",arr[i]);` instead to appropriately scan an string .

also note when ever you are scanning string char by char you have to add terminator `\0` to the end of your string.after scanning characters until element `i-1` of array add `\0` to element `i` like this `arr[i]=\0;`.

since your string isn't terminated appropriately `strlen` won't work well.

also note you should print elements of string while `v<strlen(arr)` the last char should be `\0` so you should use in `for(int v=0;v<=strlen(arr);v++)`

also pay attention to use `int main` not `void main`.

look:

```
void main()
{
    char arr[23];

    printf("Enter your name? \n");
    scanf("%s",arr);

    for(int v=0;v<strlen(arr);v++)
    {
        printf("%c",arr[v]);
    }//or instead of loop use printf("%s",arr);
}
```